# Sql Server 2016 Full Text Search Parser Case Inconsistency

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I don't understand why the SQL Server FTS parses "ESP 2" and "esp 2" differently.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"ESP 2"', 1040, null, 0);
```

> 0x00650073007000200032 1   0   1   Exact Match esp 2   0   ESP 2
>   0x006E006E0032006500730070  1   0   1   Exact Match nn2esp  0   ESP 2

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"esp 2"', 1040, null, 0);
```

> 0x006500730070 1   0   1   Exact Match esp 0   esp 2
>   0x0032  1   0   2   Exact Match 2   0   esp 2
>    0x006E006E0032 1   0   2   Exact Match nn2 0   esp 2

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems usefull :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909669/sys-dm-fts-parser-sql-full-text

Comment: Very Microsoft: it's not a bug, it's a feature! Next time Lucene!

Comment: won't the solution provided there doesnt work for now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sys.dm\_fts\_parser sql full text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909669/sys-dm-fts-parser-sql-full-text)